# Select multiple items on treeview Extendscript UI

Tags: extendscript, after-effects

I'm building a treeview for After Effects on Extendescript. I need that the user can use shift and control keys to select multiple items in the tree. The treeview has not implemented this functionality. As first step, I tryed to make a multiple selection by code. In the [documentation](http://estk.aenhancers.com/4%20-%20User-Interface%20Tools/control-objects.html#selection) says that tree.selection can be set as index or array of indices, but it doesn't work:

```
//not working
tree.selection = 0;
tree.selection = [0,1];
```

I tryed to set the selection by a direct reference to the items:

```
tree.selection = [tree.items[2], tree.items[4]];
```

But it only sets the first item of the array as selection. 
Is it posible to select multiple items on a treeview or I'm loosing something?

Comment: Have you tried `tree.items[n].selected = true`? Just a guess.

Comment: Yes, but only one item is selected at a time. `multiselect: true` at creation does not work either.